# Array Addition of elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Consider an array

```
a = [-4,58,9,,-91]
```

So I want to add these element in such way that my result will be
 `b= [-4 ,(58-4 = 54), (54+9=63),(63-91=-28) ]` so my array result is `[-4,54,63,-28]`.

Any solution?

Comment: it is not angular ................

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To modify your array in place, you can use a `forEach` loop:

```js
const a = [-4,58,9,-91];
a.forEach((elt, i, arr) => {
  if (i > 0) {
    arr[i] = elt + arr[i - 1];
  }
});

console.log(a); // [-4,54,63,-28]
```